# Why isn't my external monitor's native resolution available in Display Preferences?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, displayport

I have 22" external monitor that has a native resolution of 1680 x 1050.  When I open the display preferences I don't get it as an option.  I've tried rebooting.  That didn't help.

[image]

I have the monitor hitched up through a mini-display port VGA dongle.

Comment: can you provide the make and model? and can you confirm that your are connecting via VGA (Analog D-Connector) and not DVI (Digital) as I've seen some monitors with that particular resolution that are only fully capable of that resolution when connected via DVI and not when connected by VGA.

Comment: It's a late 2010 MBP w/ a 2.53 Ghz i5 chip. Yes, I'm using a VGA adapter.  I used to have a DVI one, but I can't find it!

Comment: the make model of the display?

Comment: It's an acer x223w

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824009145

Answer (score 1):

The problem would appear to be one that has been around for some time, at least two years according to everything I've found for example [MacRumors Forum](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=540958).

[SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/indexSRX4.html) provides a way to force a monitor into a mode that the drivers says it doesn't support.